# What's the Title for the Person Who Runs a PMO Office?

Tags: roles, terminology

I've been in several organizations that have a PMO - Project Management Office.  But I've never gotten a clear take on what the person who runs it should really be called.  I've sometimes heard him/her referred to as "the PMO" but that really doesn't make any more sense than calling the person who runs the HR department "the HR".

Does anyone have a better title for this role that makes sense?

Comment: I believe this would be a better question for PM.SE itself and not a meta question. I would recommend you move it to the site itself.

Comment: I suspect that there is no consistent title.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the title of this role is "PMO Manager".

Answer (score 0):

**PMO Leader** is occasionally used but the PMO Manager mentioned by @Marv Mills is far more common in the places I know.